# I am getting npm error while installing react navigation. Do anyone know about this issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation

I am getting an npm error while installing react-navigation. Does anyone know about this issue?

```
ERR! code 1

npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git /Users/nakul/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-818101c2

npm ERR! /Users/nakul/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-818101c2/.git: Permission denied

npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/nakul/.npm/_logs/2018-04-14T10_46_28_136Z-debug.log
```

Comment: seems like some permissions issue, have you tried with `sudo` ?

Comment: yes i m installing by using sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod -R 777 ~/.npm` then reinstall.

Or `rm -rf ~/.npm` and reinstall. `~/.npm` is a temp directory and can be safely deleted. npm will recreate this directory with right permissions.